# Dynamically allocate image in a shared_ptr each frame

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I'm trying to use shared_ptr for the first time here, but I'm having some trouble doing this.

I want to get am IplImage every frame and allocate to a shared_ptr class member, releasing the last image. It's something like this:

```
class Detector {
public: 
       void Detector::updateImage {
            main_image_.reset(cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3));
       }
private:
       boost::shared_ptr<IplImage> main_image_;
}
```

I call updateImage in a loop. cvCreateImage dynamically allocates some memory for that image size.

The first time the loop runs, everything works ok. Now, the second time I get a _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID assertion error. This happens when shared_ptr is trying to delete the pointer.

So, assuming I was doing something wrong, I tried many other options like:

```
if (!main_image_) 
    main_image_ = boost::shared_ptr<IplImage> (cvCreateImage...
else
    main_image_.reset(cvCreateImage...)
```

Didn't work also. Tried resetting the shared_ptr first, didn't work either. Tried setting a new temporary shared_ptr and assigning to my main_image_ ptr. No success.

Where am I going wrong here? Using regular pointers and releasing the image manually worked like a charm.

Thanks in advance,

Theo

Comment: What are the definitions of `IplImage` and `cvCreateImage()`?

Comment: This is not relevant to your `shared_ptr` problem, but I'd like to point out that allocating a 640x480 image for each frame seems very inefficient to me. You might want to consider reusing already allocated images. Check out a technique called "double buffering" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics).

Comment: @Maxim. IplImage is a structure used in OpenCV. It holds data and metadata for an image. cvCreateImage is also form OpenCV and allocates the necessary memory for this. 

@Emile: Of course you're right. Should be better to reuse the same image just painting everything black. Won't even be necessary to use double buffering. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you're seeing this error in a debug build?

Which method of allocating memory does `cvCreateImage()` use? `new` or `malloc()`? `boost::shared_ptr` uses `delete` to destroy the memory so there might be a chance that your system detects that the data wasn't allocated the "right way", ie by using new.

If that's the case then you'd have to use a `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter (look at the boost docs for more info) so the memory gets released correctly.

Comment: +1 even if `cvCreateImage()` does not allocate using `new`, you can assign a custom deallocator to the `shared_ptr` as the second argument in the [constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#allocator_constructor).

Comment: @Sam, that's what I was referring to as the custom deleter - I think that's what it's called in the Boost documentation...

Comment: yep, I just wanted to add a comment indicating my upvote rather than edit your answer.

Comment: @Sam and @Timo, You guys got it! cvCreateImage uses malloc to allocate the new image. I'm gonna try the custom deleter!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Theo, glad you found the problem.